# How to extract rows from a parent matrix based on column values from a second matrix (child)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrices: Parent matrix (19564 X 5) and a child matrix (3913 X 3) (sub-matrix of parent). The 3 cols in child matrix and 1st 3 cols in parent matrix are x,y and z - coordinates.

```
Parent= [x,y,z,A,B]
Child= [x,y,z]
```

I need to extract 4th and 5th column (A and B) from parent matrix corresponding to x,y,z coordinates in child matrix.

I tried using `ismember` function in `MATLAB`, but it performs a col-wise search and I don't get the desired output.

As output, I need a 3913 X 5 matrix whose 1st 3 cols are exactly same as the child matrix and then 2 additional cols (A and B) from parent matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) with the `rows` flag to match xyz coordinates in both matrices and then use the result of it to extract the required rows from the `Parent` matrix.

```
out = Parent(ismember(Parent(:,1:3), Child, 'rows'), :);
```

Comment: I think you need to change `[4 5]` to `:`, since an 3913x5 matrix is wanted.

Comment: I know it represent the columns. With `[4 5]`, `out` will be a 3913x2 matrix, while OP asks for the 3913x5 matrix. Unless you're going to append `out` to `Child`. (but that is currently not happening in the code)

Comment: @ViG You're right. OP first asked about extracting the 4th and 5th column and then asked about getting all columns. I missed that. Thanks for pointing out.